# 401 authentication error MS Graph with Outlook 365 account

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have a website where I can access to outlook accounts. I developed with MS Graph and works properly with my old App (created with a old hotmail account). I can log in and read mails folder.

A new email account have been given to me (an outlook 365 account) in order to config that website with this email account.

Now, when I set the new APP_ID and APP_PASSWORD properties in my code, website launch 401 error.

What is happening? Is anything related Outlook 365 account permission or a MS Graph problem? Have been authetication via MS Graph deprecated?

Comment: Could you post the documentation link of the api you are using?

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#readme and use Microsoft Application Registration Portal to register my application.

Comment: Have you consented your application with your new account?  You need to consent your application for access to your mailbox.

Comment: Issue has been fixed. Problem was account permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related with account permissions. I have talked with IT customer to rise permissions account and problem was fixed.